# Find $\tan 2x$, given $\tan(x+y)=3$ and $\tan(x-y)=2$

Tags: trigonometry

I am having a hard time to solve this trigonometric system of equations. The equations is as follows:

> We are given $$\tan(x+y)=3$$ $$\tan(x-y) = 2$$ 
>   and **we need to find** $$\tan2x$$

I have tried multiple ways of solving it but can't get the answer. I have tried angle addition and subtraction identities for tangent. Then I have also derived this equation $$\tan(x+y)-1=\tan(x-y)$$and tried it but without any success.

**Any help will be appreciated!**

And sorry if this is a very simple thing. I am just a new guy in the world of **trigonometry**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT:

Let $A=x+y, B=x-y$

$\tan(A+B)=\dfrac{\tan A+\tan B}{1-\tan A\tan B}$

---

Alternatively, $$x+y=m\pi+\arctan3,x-y=n\pi+\arctan2$$ where $m,n$ are arbitrary integers.

Using [Inverse trigonometric function identity doubt: $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y =-\pi+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$, when $x<0$, $y<0$, and $xy>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan/1837799#1837799),

$$\arctan3+\arctan2=\cdots=\dfrac{3\pi}4$$

Comment: @AndréNicolas, Thanks for your observation.

Comment: Thanks @lab bhattacharjee! First one is beautiful!