# Find $\arctan(\frac{1}{3})+\arctan(\frac{1}{9})+\arctan(\frac{7}{19})$

Tags: trigonometry, fractions, inverse-function

Firstly used this formula $$ \begin{align} \arctan(\alpha)+\arctan(\beta) 
& =\arctan(\frac{1-xy}{x+y}),\quad x\gt0,y\gt0 \\ &=\arctan(\frac{1-\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{9}}{\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{9}}) \\ &=\arctan(2) \end{align}$$ So it is $\arctan(2)+\arctan(\frac{7}{19}).$ Here I don't know what is the next step to solve it completely.
A SIDE NOTE: AN EDIT HAS BEEN MADE TO THIS POST, I HAVE FOUND MY MISTAKE! NOW IT IS CLEAR TO ME, THANKS!

Comment: What is $(3+i)(9+i)(19+7i)$?

Comment: Perhaps this page would interest you:
http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/simpleTrig.html

Comment: Your formula is incorrect - you're missing a $\arctan$ term.

Comment: @lordsharktheunknown It is $7i^3+109i^2+931i.$ I would like to know what is the reason behind asking this question involving complex numbers.

Comment: @Tug'tekin I am sceptical about your numbers. You are aware though, that complex numbers have arguments?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Actually, no. Because I haven't begun studying them yet.

Comment: @Tug'tekin Then you have lots of fun to look forward to!

Comment: @Tug'tekin, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct formula is:
$$\arctan(u)+\arctan(v)=\arctan \left({\frac {u+v}{1-uv}}\right)$$

So:
$$\arctan(1/3)+\arctan(1/9)=\arctan \left({\frac {6}{13}}\right)$$
$$\arctan(1/3)+\arctan(1/9)+\arctan(7/19)=
\arctan \left({\frac {6/13+7/19}{1-6/13\cdot 7/19}}\right)$$
$$=\arctan(1)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 2):

Just calculate:
$$\tan\left(\arctan\frac{1}{3}+\arctan\frac{1}{9}+\arctan\frac{7}{19}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{\frac{\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{9}}{1-\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{9}}+\frac{7}{19}}{1-\frac{\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{9}}{1-\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{9}}\cdot\frac{7}{19}}=1,$$
which gives the answer: $45^{\circ}$.