# General formula for $\arctan$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The question is to express 
$$
\arctan a_1+ \arctan a_2 + \dots + \arctan a_n
$$
as $\arctan(\cdot)$ I tried using the formula for the corresponding $\tan$ series but couldn't generalise to all cases.The principal branch is taken as $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Any ideas?

Comment: You want to generalize https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan

Comment: Have you looked at [Wikipedia on tangents of sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Tangents_of_sums)?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee yes

Comment: @RossMillikan thanks for the reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $z_n=1+ia_n$ then $\arctan a_n=\arg z_n$ and
$$\arctan a_1+ \arctan a_2 + \dots + \arctan a_n=\arg(\prod_{k=1}^n z_k)=\arctan \dfrac{{\bf Im}\ {w}}{{\bf Re}\ {w}}$$
where $\displaystyle w=\prod_{k=1}^n z_k$.

Comment: The final result should be $\arctan\dfrac{\Im a}{\Re a}$.

Comment: Yes, a good point! thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use the addition formula $$\arctan a_1 + \arctan a_2=\arctan\left(\frac{a_1+a_2}{1-a_1a_2}\right)\quad (\text{mod}\,\pi)$$ **In general, working in modulo $\pi$:**

If $n=2k, k\in\mathbb{N}$: $$\sum_{n=1}^{2k}\arctan a_n=\arctan\left({\sum_{j=1}^k\left[(-1)^{j-1}\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}\prod_{i=1}^{2j-1}a_i\right)\right]}\over{1-\sum_{j=1}^k\left[(-1)^{j-1}\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}\prod_{i=1}^{2j}a_i\right)\right]}\right)$$

If $n=2k+1, k\in\mathbb{N}$: $$\sum_{n=1}^{2k+1}\arctan a_n=\arctan\left(\frac{\sum_{j=0}^k\left[(-1)^j\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}\prod_{i=1}^{2j+1}a_i\right)\right]}{1-\sum_{j=1}^k\left[(-1)^j\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}\prod_{i=1}^{2j}a_i\right)\right]}\right)$$

Comment: $\arctan\sqrt{3}+\arctan\sqrt{3}=2\pi/3$; on the other hand $\arctan\bigl((\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{3})/(1-\sqrt{3}\sqrt{3})\bigr)=-\arctan\sqrt{3}=-\pi/3$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

From the addition formula,

$$\tan(\arctan a+\arctan b+\arctan c)=\frac{\dfrac{a+b}{1-ab}+c}{1-\dfrac{a+b}{1-ab}c}
=\dfrac{a+b+c-abc}{1-ab-bc-ca}$$

and

$$\tan(\arctan a+\arctan b+\arctan c+\arctan d)
\\=\frac{{\dfrac{a+b+c-abc}{1-ab-bc-ca}}+d}{1-\dfrac{a+b+c-abc}{1-ab-bc-ca}d}
\\=\dfrac{a+b+c+d-abc-bcd-cda-dab}{1-ab-bc-cd-da-ac-bd-ca+abcd}.$$

A regular pattern seems to emerge. We can write a recurrent form

$$\tan\left(\arctan\frac{p_{n-1}}{q_{n-1}}+\arctan a_n\right)=\frac{\dfrac{p_{n-1}}{q_{n-1}}+a_n}{1-\dfrac{p_{n-1}}{q_{n-1}}a_n}=\frac{p_{n-1}+q_{n-1}a_n}{q_{n-1}-p_{n-1}a_n}$$

and

$$\begin{cases}p_n=p_{n-1}+q_{n-1}a_n,\\q_n=q_{n-1}-p_{n-1}a_n.\end{cases}$$

From an operational point of view, this is equivalent to Nosrati's formula, where the product will be computed incrementally. The fully expanded formulas are complicated and computationally inefficient.