# Derive the conditions for $\tan^{-1}\frac{a\cos x-b\sin x}{b\cos x+a\sin x}=\tan^{-1}\frac{a}{b}-x$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

Simplify

> $$
> \tan^{-1}\frac{a\cos x-b\sin x}{b\cos x+a\sin x},\quad\text{ if }\quad\frac{a}{b}\tan x>-1
> $$

I understand the solution:
$$
L.H.S=\tan^{-1}\frac{\frac{a}{b}-\tan x}{1+\frac{a}{b}\tan x}=\tan^{-1}\big[\tan(\tan^{-1}\tfrac{a}{b}-x)\big]=\tan^{-1}\frac{a}{b}-x
$$
Alright, but what about the conditions $\frac{a}{b}\tan x>-1$ ?

**My Attempt:**

$$
\frac{-\pi}{2}<\tan^{-1}\frac{a}{b}-x<\frac{\pi}{2}\implies \frac{-\pi}{2}<x-\tan^{-1}\frac{a}{b}<\frac{\pi}{2}\\\implies \tan^{-1}\frac{a}{b}-\frac{\pi}{2}<x<\tan^{-1}\frac{a}{b}+\frac{\pi}{2}\\\implies \tan\Big[\tan^{-1}\frac{a}{b}-\frac{\pi}{2}\Big]<\tan x<\tan\Big[\tan^{-1}\frac{a}{b}+\frac{\pi}{2}\Big]\\\implies -\tan\big[\tan^{-1}\frac{a}{b}\big]
<\tan x<-\tan\big[\tan^{-1}\frac{a}{b}\big]$$

How do I proceed further and reach the given condition ?

**Note 1:** We are only considering the pricipal value branch

**Note 2:** I don't want to derive the conditions from the fact that $\cos\Big[\tan^{-1}\frac{a}{b}-x\Big]>0$

$$
\cos(\tan^{-1}\tfrac{a}{b})\cos x+\sin(\tan^{-1}\tfrac{a}{b})\sin x>0\\\implies\cos(\tan^{-1}\tfrac{a}{b})\cos x+\cos(\tan^{-1}\tfrac{a}{b})\tan(\tan^{-1}\tfrac{a}{b})\cos x\tan x>0\\\implies
\cos(\tan^{-1}\tfrac{a}{b})\cos x\Big[1+\tan(\tan^{-1}\tfrac{a}{b})\tan x\Big]>0\implies1+\tan(\tan^{-1}\tfrac{a}{b})\tan x>0\\
\implies\tfrac{a}{b}\tan x>-1
$$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan/1837799#1837799

Comment: @labbhattacharjee thanx. but could u pls assist me with my attempt, why am i not able to reach the conditions ?

Comment: From the logic cited in my link,  $$\tan^{-1}\dfrac{\dfrac ab+(-\tan x)}{1-\dfrac ab(-\tan x)}=\tan^{-1}\dfrac ab+\tan^{-1}(-\tan x)$$

$$\iff\dfrac ab\cdot(-\tan x)<1$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee pls check i have edited my post. I understand it. thats not my question. How do i reach it proceeding with my attempt ?

Comment: But $\cos y>0$ does not necessarily imply $$-\dfrac\pi2< y<\dfrac\pi2$$  Another point  $$\tan^{-1}(\tan x)$$ not necessarily $$=x$$ right?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee i think i 4got to mention i am only considering the principal value branch. In that case, $\tan^{-1}\frac{\frac{a}{b}-\tan x}{1+\frac{a}{b}\tan x}=\tan^{-1}\tfrac{a}{b}-x\implies\tfrac{-\pi}{2}<\tan^{-1}\frac{a}{b}-x<\tfrac{\pi}{2}$. And in that range $\cos\big[\tan^{-1}\frac{a}{b}-x\big]>0$, right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72092/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-ss1729).

Comment: @labbhattacharjee i am srry. i dont understand how can it be false ?
i think reverse of $\cos\big[\tan^{-1}\frac{a}{b}-x\big]>0$ is $\tan^{-1}\frac{a}{b}-x<\pi/2$. But, whats wrong in taking $\tan^{-1}\frac{\frac{a}{b}-\tan x}{1+\frac{a}{b}\tan x}=\tan^{-1}\frac{a}{b}-x\implies -\pi/2<\tan^{-1}\frac{a}{b}-x<\pi/2\implies \cos\big[\tan^{-1}\frac{a}{b}-x\big]>0$ and proceeding further with the poof ?