# Partial Derivative of arctan

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Given that $$f(x,y)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$$
Find $f_x(x,y)$

My attempt,

$$
\begin{aligned}
f_x(x,y)&=\frac{(1-xy)(1)-(x+y)(-y)}{(1-xy)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{1+y^2}{(1-xy)^2+(x+y)^2}\\
&=\frac{1+y^2}{1+y^2+x^2+x^2y^2}
\end{aligned}
$$

But the given answer is $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$.

How?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint:

$$1+x^2+y^2+x^2y^2=(1+x^2)+y^2(1+x^2)=?$$

Alternatively, see [Inverse trigonometric function identity doubt: $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y =-\pi+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$, when $x<0$, $y<0$, and $xy>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan/1837799#1837799)

Comment: Thanks ! I got it.

Answer (score 4):

Because
$$\frac{1+y^2}{1+y^2+x^2+x^2y^2}$$

and

$$\frac{1}{x^2+1}$$

are the same thing.

Comment: When $y \ne \pm i$

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, denote: $x=\tan a; y=\tan b$. Then:
$$z=\arctan \frac{\tan a+\tan b}{1-\tan a\tan b}=a+b.$$
So:
$$z_x=a_x=(\arctan x)'=\frac{1}{1+x^2}.$$