# How do I find a Taylor series of $\arctan \frac{2-2x}{1+4x}$ at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

I've been trying to find a Taylor series of $\arctan \frac{2-2x}{1+4x}$ at $x=0$
The only thing I could think of was trying to find formula for the $n$th derivative but was unable to find it so it would fit into the result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint:

$$\arctan\dfrac{2-2x}{1+4x}=\arctan\dfrac{2+(-2x)}{1-2(-2x)}=?$$

See [Inverse trigonometric function identity doubt: $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y =-\pi+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$, when $x<0$, $y<0$, and $xy>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan)

Comment: Very good hint!

Answer (score 3):

**Another hint**:

The derivative is
$$\biggl(\arctan\frac{2-2x}{1+4x}\biggr)'=-\frac 2{1+4x^2}=-2\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^n 4^n x^{2n},$$
so integrating, we get
$$\arctan\frac{2-2x}{1+4x}-\arctan 2= \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1} 4^{n+1}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}.$$