# Solving equation involving inverse trig functions

Tags: trigonometry

I'd like some help getting this question on its way, any help would be
greatly appreciated.

Solve for $x$ if $x∈\Bbb R^{+}$

$$\tan ^{-1}(2x+1)+\tan ^{-1}(2x-1)=\tan ^{-1}2$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried and what do you know about $\tan$? In particular, do you know an expression for $\tan(a+b)$?

Comment: Apply $\tan$ to both sides and exploit $\tan(a+b)=\frac{\tan(a)+\tan(b)}{1-\tan(a)\tan(b)}$. What do you get?

Comment: You may also consider that $x=\frac{1}{2}$ is a trivial solution and the LHS is an increasing function, so the trivial solution is the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Using my answer here [Inverse trigonometric function identity doubt: $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y =-\pi+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$, when $x<0$, $y<0$, and $xy>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan/1837799#1837799),

$$\arctan(2x+1)+\arctan(2x-1)=\begin{cases} \arctan\frac{2x}{1-2x^2} &\mbox{if } (2x+1)(2x-1)<1\\ \pi+\arctan\frac{2x}{1-2x^2} & \mbox{if }(2x+1)(2x-1)>1\\\text{sign}(x)\cdot\dfrac\pi2 & \mbox{if } (2x+1)(2x-1)=1\end{cases}$$

Now $\dfrac\pi2>\arctan(2)>\arctan(\sqrt3)=\dfrac\pi3$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Equal the tangents of both sides and use the addition formula for the tangent. You should obtain the quadratic equation
$$2x^2+x-1=0.$$

Comment: sorry. maybe i did some mistake.

Comment: no. sorry. it was a mistake. i am ready to upvote this answer.

Comment: but i am not allowed to upvote it any longer. sorry for downvoting. i am using stack exchange after a long time.