# How can you solve and equation with inverse functions?

Tags: trigonometry

$$\arctan(x) - \arctan(2/x) = \arctan(7/9)$$  where $x$ is positive .

The answer should be 3. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please show your working, including where you are stuck. In addition, it is always better to format your questions with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using
$$\tan(A-B)=\frac{\tan A-\tan B}{1+\tan A\tan B}$$
we get the equation
$$\frac{x-2/x}{1+2}=\frac79$$
which looks like a nice quadratic equation.

Comment: I apologise for my lack of knowledge but could you elaborate on how you got that $\tan (A-B)=\frac 79, \tan A=x$ and $\tan B=\frac 2x$?

Comment: Take the tangent of both sides.

Comment: @KM101 thank you for the reply.

Comment: Thank you sooo much!

Answer (score 0):

Using [Inverse trigonometric function identity doubt: $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y =-\pi+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$, when $x<0$, $y<0$, and $xy>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan#),

$$\arctan\dfrac2x+\arctan\dfrac79=\arctan\dfrac{18+7x}{9x-14}$$ for $\dfrac{2\cdot7}{x\cdot9}<1$ which happens if $x<0$ or if $x>\dfrac{14}9$

What if $\dfrac{14}{9x}\ge1?$