# How do I draw the graphs of $\sin^{-1}(\frac{2x}{1+x^2})$ and $\tan^{-1}(\frac{2x}{1-x^2})$?

Tags: graphing-functions, inverse-function

How do I draw the graphs of $\sin^{-1}(\frac{2x}{1+x^2})$ and $\tan^{-1}(\frac{2x}{1-x^2})$? The solution of a question in my books how these graphs and draws the conclusion that from them it is seen $0<x<1$.How do I draw these graphs and how is this conclusion obtained?

Comment: Set $y=x$ in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672575/proof-for-the-formula-of-sum-of-arcsine-functions-arcsin-x-arcsin-y  and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan

Comment: Can you clarify the question? $0 < x < 1$ for positive real $x$ is not true for the arctangent function.

Comment: @TobyMak if a and b satisfy sin^-1 (2x/1+x^2) = tan^-1 (2x/1-x^2) and |a-b| < k then k =? Answer is 2.

Comment: The second claim is not necessarily true. The first function is defined for all real $x,$ and the second is defined for all $|x|\ne 1.$