# Find all $x$ such that $\sin x = \frac{4}{5}$ and $\cos x = \frac{3}{5}$.

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, systems-of-equations

> Let 
>   $$
> \left\{ 
> \begin{array}{c}
> \sin x = \frac{4}{5} \\ 
> \cos x = \frac{3}{5}
> \end{array}
> \right. 
> $$
>
> Find all of the possible values for $x$.

**My try:** By dividing the equations we obtain $\tan x = \frac{4}{3}$ and then $$x = \arctan\frac{4}{3} + k\pi$$ 
But WolframAlpha gives 
$$x = 2k\pi + 2\arctan\frac{1}{2}$$

Using $\arctan(x)+\arctan(y) = \arctan\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$, we get $$2\arctan\frac{1}{2} = \arctan\frac{4}{3}$$ 
but the answers are different still.

Why does this happen? And what is the correct answer?

Comment: $\sin x,\cos x>0\implies x$ lies in the first quadrant

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Can provide an answer that solutions completely satisfy the equations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original (set of) equations implies $\tan x=\frac{4}{3}$ but not the other way around. When you solve $\tan x=\frac{4}{3}$ you get the solutions of your original equation **and** the solutions $\sin x=\frac{-4}{5}$, $\cos x=\frac{-3}{5}$.

Comment: Thanks, so after getting $x = \arctan\frac{4}{3} + k\pi$ what is the next step?

Comment: If $k$ is even then it's the solution of your equation, if $k$ is odd it's the solution of the wrong one ($\sin\theta=-4/5$, $\cos\theta=-3/5$).

Comment: Think about the position of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ in the unit circle. Clearly they are in the first quadrant, so any possible answers $x$ should satisfy $$2k\pi\leq x\leq 2k\pi+\frac{1}{2}\pi.$$

Comment: @FlorisClaassens That's right, so in general for solving trigonometric equations putting the answer in the original equations is always necessary?

Comment: If you had just solved arccos($\frac{3}{5}$) and arcsin($\frac{4}{5}$) you can find the answers by taking the values they both have in common. In that case it is not necessary to go back to the original equations. If you use the arctan way, which I would advice it is necessary. In all cases of trigonometry I would definitely advise to always consider the original equations to see if the answers you got make sense.

Comment: @S.H.W In general for solving _any_ equations it should always be possible to put the answer back in the original equation. If you can be absolutely sure that all your steps were "if and only if" steps then you may be able to skip that final check, but if you do not know how to prove that it is unnecessary, you should plug back into the final equation before writing your final answer.

Comment: @FlorisClaassens Okay, thanks a lot.

Comment: @DavidK It was really a helpful advice, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

$\cos x=\dfrac35$

$\implies x=2n\pi\pm\arccos\dfrac35$

As for $x>0,\arccos x=\arcsin\sqrt{1-x^2}=\arctan\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x$

$\implies x=2n\pi\pm\arcsin\dfrac45$ where $n$ is any integer

Now , $\sin x=\sin\left(2n\pi\pm\arcsin\dfrac45\right)=\pm\dfrac45$

But $\sin x=+\dfrac45$

$$\implies x=2n\pi+\arcsin\dfrac45=2n\pi+\arccos\dfrac35=2n\pi+\arctan\dfrac43$$

Further if $2y=\arctan\dfrac43,\dfrac43=\tan2y=\dfrac{2\tan y}{1-\tan^2y}$

Solve the  quadratic equation in $\tan y$ to find the values to be $\dfrac12,-2$

But as $0<2y<\dfrac\pi2, y=\arctan\dfrac12$

which can be validated using [Inverse trigonometric function identity doubt: $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y =-\pi+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$, when $x<0$, $y<0$, and $xy>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan)