# Conditions for trigonometric identity $\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y=\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}$, $x>0$,$y>0$

Tags: trigonometry

$\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y=\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}$, $x>0$,$y>0$

This is the standard trigonometric identity for $x>0$,$y>0$

Now I want to know why it can't be $x>=0,y>=0$

**To know that, I tried to prove for $x>=0,y>=0$ just to see if I get any contradiction**

$\tan^{-1}x\in\left[0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$, $\tan^{-1}y\in\left[0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$

So $\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y\in\left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$
$$A=\tan^{-1}x,B=\tan^{-1}y$$ 
$$\tan A=x,\tan B=y$$

$$\tan(A-B)=\dfrac{\tan A-\tan B}{1+\tan A\tan B}$$
$$\tan(A-B)=\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}$$

Taking $\tan^{-1}$ on both sides

$$\tan^{-1}(\tan(A-B))=\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}$$

As $A-B \in \left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$

$$A-B=\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}$$

So I didn't get any contradiction during the entire result. So is $x=0$ or $y=0$ not taken in domain to avoid corner conditions or there is something else?

Comment: This is, of course, true for $x=0$. You don't even need to prove it - just substitute $x=0$ into the original formula. Your proof is fine.

Comment: Use $$\tan^{-1}(-z)=-\tan^{-1}z$$See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan/1837799#1837799

Comment: sorry but I didn't get you, $x=0$, $y=0$ is satisfying the original equation.

Comment: Why do you think that this is invalid for some negative values of $x,y$? Indeed it is, too! The only time it is invalid is when $x,y$ are such that $\arctan x-\arctan y$ falls outside the range $(-π/2,π/2).$

Answer (score 0):

Just to add we can't take $x$ as any arbitary R(real), $y$ as any arbitary(real) because of the following issue.

$A=\tan^{-1}x$, $B=\tan^{-1}y$

if $x\in R$, $\tan^{-1}x \in \left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$

if $y\in R$, $\tan^{-1}y \in \left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$

So $\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y \in (-\pi,\pi)\tag{1}$

But for $\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y=\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}$ to be valid, 
 $\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y \in \left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$

But we had $\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y \in (-\pi,\pi)$ in equation $(1)$

So we can't take $x$ as any arbitary real. Just thought to mention it because one will not find this in many textbooks. May be this would be of some help to beginners.

Comment: The claim that you can't take $x$ or $y$ to be negative is wrong! Take $x=y=-100,$ for example.

Comment: I am not claiming that x cann't be negative, I am just claiming that we can't allow $x\in R$. Just see the proof again.

Comment: ok yeah, you were correct, at the last I did mistake, but I have updated my answer now.

Comment: On the contrary you do. In any case we have to allow $x,y$ to be real, otherwise what do we mean by $\arctan x$ otherwise, for example?

Comment: bro, I  am saying "all" real,

Comment: Then you'd better clarify that in the earlier parts of your answer. Using the word *arbitrary* may help.

Comment: yeah that would be better.

Comment: so I think the rule of $x>0, y>0$ was made in order to minimize the conditions and to be safe. What do you say?

Comment: I agree. Although of course that wouldn't necessarily work for the case when you're *adding* arcs.

Comment: when we are adding arcs , then also we can't take any arbitary real. There are two conditions in that.

Comment: Of course we can't. My point was that restricting $x$ and $y$ to be positive wouldn't necessarily help in that case.

Comment: yeah so we have two cases over there ,$xy<1$  or $xy>1$ and ofcourse $x>0 $ and $y>0$

Comment: I *dis*agree with that, but *more* importantly, I've made the point I wanted to make and really am not interested in bantering further. Thank you. :)