# Trying to find $\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y$ for $\forall~x,y$

Tags: trigonometry

Suppose we want to calculate $\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y$ for $\forall~x,y$

We already know $\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y=\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}$ for $x>0$ and $y>0$, but we will not make use of it as we have to prove for $\forall$ $x,y$

$$\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y=\theta\tag{1}$$

Let's find range of $\theta$, assuming $x$ and $y$ to be independent variables

$$\theta\in(-\pi,\pi)$$

Taking $\tan$ on both sides of equation $1$

$$\dfrac{\tan(\tan^{-1}x)-\tan(\tan^{-1}y)}{1+\tan(\tan^{-1}x)\cdot \tan(\tan^{-1}y)}=\tan\theta$$

$$\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}=\tan\theta$$

Taking $\tan^{-1}$ on both sides

$$\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}=\tan^{-1}(\tan\theta)$$

$$\tan^{-1}(\tan\theta)=\begin{cases}
    \pi+\theta,&-\pi<\theta<\dfrac{-\pi}{2} \\
    \theta,&-\dfrac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\dfrac{\pi}{2} \\
    -\pi+\theta, & \dfrac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\pi
  \end{cases}$$

So

$$\theta=\begin{cases}
    -\pi+\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy},&-\pi<\theta<\dfrac{-\pi}{2} \\
    \tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy},&-\dfrac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\dfrac{\pi}{2} \\
    \pi+\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}, & \dfrac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\pi
  \end{cases}$$

$$\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y=\begin{cases}
    -\pi+\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy},&-\pi<\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y<-\dfrac{\pi}{2} \\
    \tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy},&-\dfrac{\pi}{2}<\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y<\dfrac{\pi }{2}\\
    \pi+\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}, & \dfrac{\pi}{2}<\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y<\pi
  \end{cases}$$

$$\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y=\begin{cases}
    -\pi+\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}, & \tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y\in\left(-\pi,\dfrac{-\pi}{2}\right)\\
    \tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy},& \tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y\in\left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)\\
    \pi+\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}, & \tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y\in\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2},\pi\right)
  \end{cases}$$

$$\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y=\begin{cases}
    -\pi+\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}, & \dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}\in\left(0,\infty\right)\\
    \tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy},&\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}\in\left(-\infty,\infty\right)\\
    \pi+\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}, & \dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}\in\left(-\infty,0\right)
  \end{cases}$$

$$\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y=\begin{cases}
    -\pi+\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}, & \dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}>0\\
    \tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy},&\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}\in\left(-\infty,\infty\right)\\
    \pi+\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}, & \dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}\in\left(-\infty,0\right)
  \end{cases}$$

**Let's take a look at first branch**

$\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}>0$, only in two following cases

**Case $1$:**

$x>y$ and $xy>-1$

In this case, L.H.S= $\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y$ will be positive as $\tan^{-1}$ is increasing function but R.H.S=$-\pi+\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}$ is always negative because range of $\tan^{-1}$ is $\left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$. So we got contradiction in this case

**Case $2$:**

$x<y$ and $xy<-1$ $\implies$ $x<0$ and $y>0$ (just determining the sign of $x$ and $y$)

So in this case this branch looks perfectly valid.

**Let's take a look at third branch**

$\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}<0$, only in two following cases

**Case $1$:**

$x<y$ and $xy>-1$

In this case, L.H.S= $\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y$ will be negative as $\tan^{-1}$ is increasing function but R.H.S=$-\pi+\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}$ is always positive because range of $\tan^{-1}$ is $\left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$. So we got contradiction in this case

**Case $2$:**

$x>y$ and $xy<-1$ $\implies$ $y<0$ and $x>0$ (just determining the sign of $x$ and $y$)

So in this case this branch looks perfectly valid.

**Let's take a look at second branch**

This branch looks perfectly valid for all cases, but let's see if is it actually?

**Case $1$:** $x>0,y>0$, $x>y$

L.H.S is positive and R.H.S is also positive, perfectly valid.

**Case $2$:** $x>0,y>0$, $x<y$

L.H.S is negative and R.H.S is also negative, perfectly valid.

**Case $3$:** $x<0,y<0$, $x>y$

L.H.S is positive and R.H.S is also positive, perfectly valid.

**Case $4$:** $x<0,y<0$, $x<y$

L.H.S is negative and R.H.S is also negative, perfectly valid.

**Case $5$:** $x>0,y<0$, $xy>-1$ and $xy<0$

L.H.S is positive and R.H.S is also positive, perfectly valid.

**Case $5$:** $x>0,y<0$, $xy<-1$

L.H.S is positive and R.H.S is negative, got contradiction.

**Case $7$:** $x<0,y>0$, $xy<-1$

L.H.S is negative and R.H.S is positive, got contradiction.

**Case $8$:** $x<0,y>0$, $xy>-1$ and $xy<0$

L.H.S is negative and R.H.S is negative, perfectly valid.

So finally we can write

$$\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y=\begin{cases}
    -\pi+\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}, &x<0 \text{ and } y>0 \text { and } xy<-1\\
    \pi+\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}, & x>0 \text{ and } y<0 \text { and } xy<-1\\
   \tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy},& \text{ otherwise }
  \end{cases}$$

One can also derive $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y$ by the above formula

$$\tan^{-1} x+\tan^{-1} (-y)=\begin{cases}
    -\pi+\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}, &x<0 \text{ and } y>0 \text { and } xy<-1\\
    \pi+\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}, & x>0 \text{ and } y<0 \text { and } xy<-1\\
   \tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy},& \text{ otherwise }
  \end{cases}$$

Replace $y$ by $-y$

$$\tan^{-1} x+\tan^{-1} (y)=\begin{cases}
    -\pi+\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy}, &x<0 \text{ and } -y>0 \text { and } -xy<-1\\
    \pi+\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy}, & x>0 \text{ and } -y<0 \text { and } -xy<-1\\
   \tan^{-1}\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy},& \text{ otherwise }
  \end{cases}$$

$$\tan^{-1} x+\tan^{-1} (y)=\begin{cases}
    -\pi+\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy}, &x<0 \text{ and } y<0 \text { and } xy>1\\
    \pi+\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy}, & x>0 \text{ and } y>0 \text { and } xy>1\\
   \tan^{-1}\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy},& \text{ otherwise }
  \end{cases}$$

Comment: Use $\arctan(-y)=-\arctan(y)$ and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Prove the following formula valid for $x y\neq -1$
\begin{equation}
\tan^{-1}(x)-\tan^{-1}(y) = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x-y}{1+x y}\right) + \frac{\pi}{4}(\operatorname{sgn}(x)-\operatorname{sgn}(y))(1 - \operatorname{sgn}(1+x y))
\end{equation}
For this, let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be the left hand side and the right hand side respectively. When $y\ne 0$, note that $f'$ and $g'$ are defined and equal on ${\mathbb R}\setminus\{-1/y\}$ and that $f$ and $g$ have the same limits at $\pm\infty$.

Comment: yes,exactly for $x<0$, $y>0$, this formula gives $-\pi+tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}$

Comment: In your second branch, you can decide the constants by taking the limits when $x\rightarrow \pm \infty$.

Comment: why you made $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$, it should be actually $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: I don't think so, because the product of the last 2 parenthesis is either -4, 0 or 4, so it gives equalities such as $-\pi/2 = \pi/2 - \pi$ etc.

Comment: see for $x>0$, $y<0$, $xy<-1$, for this I am getting $-\pi+tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}$, and your formula is giving $tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}+\pi$, ok its correct.

Comment: No, in that case, my formula gives $\pi + \tan^{-1}(...)$

Comment: yeah I corrected,just see

Comment: I am figuring out for other cases and checking them

Comment: but why in text books they tell you for $x>0,y>0$

Comment: also see the latest conclusion in my post.

Comment: What is $\rm sgn (\cdot ) $?

Comment: @MrPie sgn is the sign function which value is -1, 0 or 1 depending on the sign of its argument.

Comment: Thanks :) ${}{} $

Answer (score -1):

You must take principal value.
In this case the principal value will be tan^(-1)(x-y)/(1+xy).
Hope you know what principal value is.

Comment: did you read the question and what it is trying to say?

Comment: just go through it, you will get the issue I am facing.

Answer (score -1):

When X,Y $\gt$ 0 you can use principle form of $$tan^{-1}(X)-tan^{-1}(Y)=tan^{-1}(\frac{X-Y}{1+XY})$$
For either X or Y is negative then first use $$tan^{-1}(-a)=-tan^{-1}(a)$$
Then use formula accordingly.
$$ $$
Either $$ tan^{-1}(X)-tan^{-1}(Y) $$
$$Or $$
$$tan^{-1}(X)+tan^{-1}(Y)$$

Comment: i am trying to find for $\forall$ $x,y$. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: I am also taking about for all X and Y takeing indendently X , Y positive and negative

Comment: I did that, please see the cases in the question and what issue I am facing there.

Comment: Do you mean to say there are more cases than difference or addition of to inverse. Both take care of all cases and are interchangeable as X or Y is +ve or -ve . With individual formula of difference or sum taking all possible values of X , Y will always has all cases you mentioned . And more with the formula of sum.

Comment: please see the answer by @Gribouillis, you will understand what we are trying to address here.

Comment: see my latest conclusion in my post.