# Differentiating trigonometric function with respect to another trigonometric function

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, differential-forms

I am unable to get even a Lil bit of clue of How to differentiate

[image: \cos ^{-1}\dfrac {1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}]

with respect to

[image: \tan ^{-1}\dfrac {2x}{1-x^{2}}]

Can I get some support here... I am tryin' to figure this math out... But I lack a few techniques.

Comment: What does it mean to differentiate one function with respect to another?  I am not entirely sure what you mean.  Rewording the problem might help everybody.

Comment: Differentiate the first one by the 2nd one

Comment: Since you repeated the phrase, I'm going to repeat the question: what does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the $2$ functions be $u(x)$ and $v(x)$.
Then $$\frac{du(x)}{dv(x)} = \frac{du(x)/dx}{dv(x)/dx}$$

In this case $u(x) =\cos^{-1}\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2} $ and $v(x) = \tan^{-1}\frac{2x}{1-x^2}$

Comment: Yes... this is the thing... thank God you got what I meant to say!!!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: You can further deduce that $\cos^{-1}\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2} = 2\tan^{-1}x$ and $\tan^{-1}\frac{2x}{1-x^2}=2\tan^{-1}x$ under certain conditions.

Comment: YES..... I remember that formula...Appreciate your co-operation, Boss @Ak19

Comment: The result is 1... I solved it...

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $z=\arctan x,-\dfrac\pi2<z<\dfrac\pi2$ and $x=\tan z$

$$\cos^{-1}\dfrac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}=\cos^{-1}(\cos2z)=\begin{cases}2z &\mbox{if }0\le2z\le\pi \\-2z & \mbox{if }0\le-2z\le\pi\iff-\pi\le2z\le0 \end{cases}$$

So, 
$$\dfrac{d\cos^{-1}(\cos2z))}{dz}=?$$

Set $y=x$ in [Inverse trigonometric function identity doubt: $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y =-\pi+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$, when $x<0$, $y<0$, and $xy>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan/1837799#1837799)