# Show $\arctan(x+1) - \arctan(x) = \arctan(\frac{1}{x^2 + x +1})$

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

Show that for all real $x$:

$$\arctan(x+1) - \arctan(x) = \arctan(\frac{1}{x^2 + x +1})$$

This is what I got so far: 
$$\arctan(x+1/x) = \arctan(1/x^2 + x +1) \iff \\
    x+1/x = 1/(x+1)^2 - x \iff \\
    (x+1)^3-x^2-2x = 0$$

But then I get stuck and feel like there is something I'm missing or there is some smarter way of doing it.

Comment: $$\arctan(-y)=-\arctan y$$ and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan/1837799#1837799