# Two answers of $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\{\cot ^{-1}\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\}$

Tags: derivatives, inverse-function

> If $$y=\cot ^{-1}\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$$ then $\dfrac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}=?$

By taking $x=\tan y$  ,then

$y=\cot ^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1+\tan y}{1-\tan y}\right)$

$y=\cot ^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\cot y+1}{\cot y-1}\right)$

$y=\cot ^{-1}\left(\cot\left(y-\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)$

$y'=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$

But if we differentiate directly(by chain rule) then we get answer $-\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$ ?

thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very first thing you did wrong was substituting $x=\tan y$. How can you do that when $y$ is itself a function of $x$?

Secondly, when you apply the chain rule, you should get it's derivative as $y'=-\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$.

Now if you want to proceed via a substitution, substitute $x=\tan \theta$ and since $x \in \mathbb{R}-\{1\}$, we have $\theta \in \left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)-\{\dfrac{\pi}{4}\}$ so that you finally get $$y=\cot ^{-1}\left(\cot\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}-\theta\right)\right)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{\pi}{4}-\theta~~~~ \text{for} ~\theta\in \left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right) \\
\dfrac{5\pi}{4}-\theta ~~~~\text{for} ~\theta \in \left(\dfrac{\pi}{4},\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)\end{cases}$$ and since we have $\dfrac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d \theta}=-1$ for both situations and we had from $x=\tan \theta$, $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\theta}=1+x^2$, we get $y'=-\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$.

Comment: $y=\cot ^{-1}\left(\cot\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}-\theta\right)\right)$ I think it will be theta - pie/4 ?

Comment: @Ishan: See the identity for [cotangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#cite_ref-mathworld_addition_13-0). You have written it wrong in the question too.

Comment: oh,yes actually it was misprinted in my book,now after that there is no problem !

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\cot^{-1}\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}=\dfrac\pi2-\tan\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}$$

Now use [Inverse trigonometric function identity doubt: $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y =-\pi+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$, when $x<0$, $y<0$, and $xy>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan/1837799#1837799)