# Find the value of $\tan ^{-1}(\frac 12 \tan 2A)+\tan^{-1} ( \cot A) +\tan ^{-1}(\cot ^3 A)$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

$\tan ^{-1}(\frac 12 \tan 2A)+\tan^{-1} ( \cot A) +\tan ^{-1}(\cot ^3 A)=\begin{cases}
0 & \frac {\pi} 4\lt A \le \frac {\pi} 2\\
\pi & 0\le A \le \frac {\pi} 2
\end {cases} $

**Try**
$\tan ^{-1}(\cot A) +\tan^{-1} (\cot^3 A) =\tan^{-1} (-\frac 12 \tan 2A) $
Now the problem reduces to finding the value of
$\tan ^{-1}(\frac 12 \tan 2A)+\tan ^{-1}(-\frac 12 \tan 2A)$
Now when $\frac {\pi} 4\lt A \le \frac {\pi} 2$ then $2A$ lies in the second quadrant, so the value of $\tan 2A $ is negative there, hence the value of $\frac 12 \tan 2A$ will be negative and the value of $-\frac 12 \tan 2A$ will be positive. I'm stucked here. How to justify the next steps from this calculation in the way I'm trying to justify by considering quadrant.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity for adding inverse tangents has cases:
$$\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y=
\begin{cases}
\tan^{-1}\frac{x+y}{1-xy} & xy < 1 \\
\pi+\tan^{-1}\frac{x+y}{1-xy} & xy > 1,x>0 \\
-\pi+\tan^{-1}\frac{x+y}{1-xy} & xy > 1,x<0 \\
\end{cases}$$
That gives us $\tan^{-1}(\cot A)+\tan^{-1}(\cot^3 A)=\varepsilon\pi+\tan^{-1}\left(-\frac 12\tan 2A\right)$ where $\varepsilon=1$ if $A\in (0,\pi/4)$, $\varepsilon=0$ if $A\in(\pi/4,3\pi/4)$ and $\varepsilon=-1$ if $A\in(3\pi/4,\pi)$. For example, when $A\in(0,\pi/4)$, we have $\cot A>1\Rightarrow \cot^3 A>1$ so $\cot A\cdot\cot^3 A>1$ and we end up in the second case of the identity above. Since the inverse tangent is an odd function, i.e. $\tan^{-1}(-t)=-\tan^{-1}t$, adding $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac 12\tan 2A\right)$ cancels out $\tan^{-1}\left(-\frac 12\tan 2A\right)$ so the final result is:
$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac 12\tan 2A\right)+\tan^{-1}(\cot A)+\tan^{-1}(\cot^3 A)=
\begin{cases}
\pi, & A\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \\
0, & A\in\left(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{4}\right) \\
-\pi, & A\in\left(\frac{3\pi}{4},\pi\right)
\end{cases}$$
Notice that the expression is $\pi$-periodic so it's sufficient to evaluate it in those three intervals.