# why is this method of solving $\tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{y})-\tan^{-1}(\frac{x-y}{x+y})$ wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inverse-function

$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x-y}{x+y}\right)$$
let this be equal to $A$
so $\tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{y})-\tan^{-1}(\frac{x-y}{x+y})=A$
thus $$\frac{x(x+y)-y(x-y)}{y(x+y)+x(x-y)}=\tan(A)$$
which means that the original function is dependent on both $x$ and $y$,

however, my book says it's independent of both.

I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: How did you go the the last equation from $A$ to $\tan(A)$?

Comment: I took tan on both sides

Comment: Numerator should have x(x+y) and denominator should have  y(x+y).

Comment: Use [this](http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.21.E4) on the left-hand side.

Comment: that's what I used

Comment: @insipidintegrator, I thought I had edited that, I''l change it now

Comment: Yeah, then after simplifying you get tan A =1.

Comment: oh, in that case I must have made a calculation error, thanks!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan