# If $R \sin \psi = r \sin \phi$ and $R \cos \psi = -ar \cos \phi$, what are $R$ and $\psi$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, systems-of-equations, computer-algebra-systems

Given $$-ar \cos \phi = R \cos \psi \\
r \sin \phi = R \sin \psi$$

how do I find $R, \psi$ in terms of $r, \phi$?

My work so far below:

---

$$\tan \psi = \frac 1 {-a} \tan \phi \\
\psi = \arctan(\frac {-1} a \tan \phi)$$ and $$R^2 = R^2 \cos^2 \psi + R^2 \sin^2 \psi = r^2 \sin^2 \phi + a^2 r^2 \cos^2 \phi \\
R = r \sqrt{a^2 \cos^2 \phi + \sin^2 \phi}.$$

---

**UPDATE:** I previously tried using Wolfram Alpha, but it's been pointed out that I used it incorrectly.  For reference, my [incorrect usage gave](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve+for+R%2C+psi%3A+-a+*+r+cos+phi+%3D+R+cos+phi%2C+r+*+sin+phi+%3D+R+sin+psi)

$$R = -ar \\
\psi = -\arcsin \left ( \frac { \sin \phi} a \right ).$$

But even after correcting, we still get [very different values for $\psi$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve+for+R%2C+psi%3A+-a+*+r+cos+phi+%3D+R+cos+psi%2C+r+*+sin+phi+%3D+R+sin+psi).

Comment: It seems in your wolfram alpha link it you accidentally made one of the $\psi$ into a $\phi$. Look at the first equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disregarding the "simpler" solutions (where at least one of $R$, $r$, $a$, $\sin(\phi)$ or $\cos(\phi)$ is equal to $0$), it's a matter of simplification. It seems that Wolfram|Alpha (for whatever reason) starts from the identity
\begin{align}
\tan\left(\frac{\psi}{2}\right)&=\csc(\psi)-\cot(\psi)\\
&=\frac{1}{\sin(\psi)}-\frac{\cos(\psi)}{\sin(\psi)}\\
&=\frac{R}{r\sin(\phi)}-\frac{\frac{-ar}{R}\cos(\phi)}{\frac{r}{R}\sin(\phi)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sin(\phi)}\left(\frac{R}{r}+a\cos(\phi)\right)\\
&=\csc(\phi)\left(\sqrt{a^2\cos^2(\phi)+\sin^2(\phi)}+a\cos(\phi)\right)
\end{align}
where the positive root $R=r\sqrt{a^2\cos^2(\phi)+\sin^2(\phi)}$ is assumed (the negative root just changes the corresponding sign). Now, knowing that due to the periodicity of $\tan(\cdot)$, solving $\tan(x)=\tan(y)$ implies $x=y+\pi n,n\in\mathbb{Z}$, we have
\begin{align}  
\Rightarrow\quad \frac{\psi}{2}&=\arctan\left[\csc(\phi)\left(\sqrt{a^2\cos^2(\phi)+\sin^2(\phi)}+a\cos(\phi)\right)\right]+\pi n\,,\quad n\in\mathbb{Z}\\
\Rightarrow\quad \psi&=2\left(\arctan\left[\csc(\phi)\left(\sqrt{a^2\cos^2(\phi)+\sin^2(\phi)}+a\cos(\phi)\right)\right]+\pi n\right)\,,\quad n\in\mathbb{Z}\,,\quad (1)
\end{align}
which is equivalent to the solution given by Wolfram|Alpha. The solution considering the negative root for $R$ is also correct, after a little algebra.

Moreover, and regardless of the derivation above, your solution is **also correct**, albeit considering the periodicity of $\tan(\cdot)$ as follows:
\begin{align}
 \tan(\psi)=\frac{−1}{a}\tan(\phi)\quad\Rightarrow \quad \psi=\arctan\left(-\frac{1}{a}\tan(\phi)\right)+\pi m,\quad m\in\mathbb{Z}\,,
\quad (2)\end{align}
where the periodicity can yield another integer as the Wolfram expression.

---

However, the **interesting** question is to show that these two expressions yield the same solution set, that is, they are essentially the same but might differ by difference of an integer multiple of $\pi$ due to periodicity. So, for the sake of ***algebraic fun***, I set to demonstrate that the arctangents in (1) and (2) are equal, up to a multiple of $\pi$ that would be absorbed by $m$ or $n$. This is equivalent to considering the required bias that operations and properties involving multiple $\arctan(\cdot)$ (like sums or products) require to ensure that every copy of $\arctan$ is still defined in the interval $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ (see, for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan)). Let $u=\tan(\phi)/a$, and we can rewrite
\begin{align}
\csc(\phi)\left(\sqrt{a^2\cos^2(\phi)+\sin^2(\phi)}+a\cos(\phi)\right)&=\sqrt{\frac{a^2\cos^2(\phi)}{\sin^2(\phi)}+1}+\frac{a}{\tan(\phi)}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{u^2}+1}+\frac{1}{u}\\
&=\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}+1}\right)^{-1}\,,
\end{align}
and we aim to prove that
\begin{align}
2\arctan\left[\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}+1}\right)^{-1}\right]=\arctan\left(-u\right)+\pi k\,,\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}\,.
\end{align}

Invoking the [following identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Relationships_among_the_inverse_trigonometric_functions):
\begin{align}
\arctan(-x)&=-\arctan(x)\,,\\
\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)&=\begin{cases}\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(x)&\text{for }x>0\\-\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(x)&\text{for }x<0\end{cases}\quad\,,\\
\arctan(x)&=2\arctan\left(\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)\,,
\end{align}
we can see that if $u>0$, then $\frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}+1}>0$ and
\begin{align}
2\arctan\left[\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}+1}\right)^{-1}\right]
&=2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left[\frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}+1}\right]\right)\\
&=\pi-2\arctan\left[\frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}+1}\right]\\
&=-\arctan\left[u\right]+\pi\\
&=\arctan\left[-u\right]+\pi\,,
\end{align}

and for $u<0$ we see that $\frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}+1}<0$, thus
\begin{align}
2\arctan\left[\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}+1}\right)^{-1}\right]
&=2\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left[\frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}+1}\right]\right)\\
&=-\pi-2\arctan\left[\frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}+1}\right]\\
&=-\arctan\left[u\right]-\pi\\
&=\arctan\left[-u\right]-\pi\,.
\end{align}

Choosing $k=\pm 1$ according to the sign of $u$ proves the claim.

Answer (score 0):

The system of equations you entered in Wolfram Alpha is different from the one you posted here in the question.

When [Wolfram Alpha solves the correct system](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve+for+R%2C+psi%3A+-a+*+r+cos+phi+%3D+R+cos+psi%2C+r+*+sin+phi+%3D+R+sin+psi), the solution is more in line with what you derived I think.

Comment: Thank you for catching that.  But even after the correction, Wolfram's solution is different than mine.

Comment: I think that Wolfram alpha somehow struggles simplifying the expression of $\psi$. Maybe plotting your expression of $\psi$ and the one from Wolfram together could confirm that both solutions are in fact equal?