# What is wrong with this substitution?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, substitution

In a problem, we have to differentiate : $$ y = \arcsin (2 x \sqrt{1 - x^2}),$$ given: $$-{1/(\sqrt2)} < x <{1/(\sqrt2)}$$.

*My approach* :

Put $x = \cos (p)$, so y reduces to:-
$y = 2p = 2 \arccos (x)  \implies$
${dy}/{dx}$ $ = -{2}/{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

But the solution given is without the minus sign, so I am doing something wrong here but don't know what.

So please tell me what I am doing wrong and how to correct it.

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672575/proof-for-the-formula-of-sum-of-arcsine-functions-arcsin-x-arcsin-y and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764431/solving-arcsin-left2x-sqrt1-x2-right-2-arcsin-x

Comment: Thanks for the edits guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\le x\le\dfrac1{\sqrt2}$$

If $x=\cos P, \dfrac\pi4\le P\le\dfrac{3\pi}4$ as $0\le\arccos x\le\pi$

$\implies\dfrac\pi2\le2P\le\dfrac{3\pi}2$

But as $-\dfrac\pi2\le\arcsin(\sin2P)\le\dfrac\pi2$

$\arcsin(\sin2P)=\pi-2P=\pi-2\arccos x$

Comment: Thanks for answering. Now I understood all but the last line, as I have learned that $\arcsin (\sin x) = x $ ; is that wrong? Why is it $\pi - 2P $ here?

Comment: @MrReality, See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values

Comment: I could find only $\sin ( \arcsin x) = x $ there, related to this in the *Basic Properties* section.

Comment: @MrReality, True. But inverse trigonometric functions are multi valued. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTrigonometricFunctions.html

Comment: Yes I know they are. But I don't understand how you got to the last step. ( In my course textbook all that's given is: For *suitable values of domain*, $\arcsin (\sin x) = x $. ) Can you please point me to somewhere where I can read up on what to do in such cases, when the domains are '*unsuitable*' like here?

Comment: @MrReality,  Make sure that inverse trig function values lie in the principal ranges. See also :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502189/why-is-arctan-fracxy1-xy-arctan-x-arctan-y

Comment: >> Make sure that inverse trig function values lie in the principal ranges − How to do that? Isn't there a resource somewhere on internet that tells this? (Because I don't follow from where you got π in the last step).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74554/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-mr-reality).