# Trigonometry basic proof problem

Tags: trigonometry

I tried to solve but I think I am making a mistake somewhere. Could you help me solving this?

Show that $\arctan(\frac{1}{4}) + \arctan(\frac{3}{5})= \frac{\pi}{4}$

Hence or otherwise, find the value of $\arctan(4)+ \arctan(\frac{3}{5})$

So i did $\tan(x)= \dfrac{1}{4}$ and $\tan(y)= \dfrac{3}{5}$ then, I added them which is $\dfrac{17}{20}= 0.85$ and this gives $40$ degrees.

I am confused.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so that we can spot the mistake

Comment: The mistake was that you added the values of $\tan x$ and $\tan y$, but to find the tangent of a sum, you would use the formulas posted below.

Comment: As a first step find $\frac{m_1+m_2}{1-m_1  m_2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\tan x=\frac14$ and $\tan y=\frac35$,$$\tan(x+y)=\frac{\tan(x)+\tan(y)}{1-\tan(x)\tan(y)}=\frac{\frac{17}{20}}{1-\frac3{20}}=1.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: then how do i find find the value of arctan(4)+ arctan(5/3)?

Comment: @QuantumCasanova If $\tan\alpha=\frac14$, then $\tan\left(\frac\pi2-\alpha\right)=\cot\alpha=\frac1{\tan\alpha}=4$. Again, can you take it from here?

Comment: I would be very pleased if you continued :)

Comment: If $\tan\alpha=4$, then $\tan\left(\frac\pi2-\alpha\right)=\frac14$ and if $\tan\beta=\frac53$, then $\tan\left(\frac\pi2-\beta\right)=\frac35$. Therefore, $\left(\frac\pi2-\alpha\right)+\left(\frac\pi2-\beta\right)=\frac\pi4$, which means that $\alpha+\beta=\frac{3\pi}4$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Recall that

$$\arctan x +\arctan y=\arctan\frac{x+y}{1-xy}$$

take a look here for the [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/502189/505767).