# Inverse trigonometry: How to find $x$

Tags: inverse-function

When $\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1+x²}\right)=2\tan^{-1}(x)$? I thought that it was for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ but it was incorrect, so please help!

Comment: From desmos, the answer is $-1 \le x \le 1$.

Comment: Please see the [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial.

Comment: I think your answer is correct. Every real number $x$ satisfies this equation.

Comment: Is there any feedback that accompanies the "incorrect" answer you were given?

Comment: The correct one was like.                                                            Sin^-1(2x/1-x²)= -π-2 tan^-1(x)  if x<-1                                       and.                   =2tan^-1(x)     if -1<x<1.                                   and.                    =π-2tan^-1(x)     if x>1.                                     Sorry but there is equality sign on my keypad. But how??

Answer (score 1):

Use

[Inverse trigonometric function identity doubt: $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y =-\pi+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$, when $x<0$, $y<0$, and $xy>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan)

OR

[Why is $\arctan\frac{x+y}{1-xy} = \arctan x +\arctan y$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502189/why-is-arctan-fracxy1-xy-arctan-x-arctan-y)

$$2\arctan x=\begin{cases} \arctan\dfrac{2x}{1-x^2} &\mbox{if } x^2<1\\ \pi+\arctan\dfrac{2x}{1-x^2} & \mbox{if } x^2>1\\\text{sign}(x)\cdot\dfrac\pi2 & \mbox{if } x^2=1\end{cases} $$

Finally if $\arctan\dfrac{2x}{1-x^2}=y,\tan y=\dfrac{2x}{1-x^2},-\dfrac\pi2<y<\dfrac\pi2$

$\sec y=+\sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{2x}{1-x^2}\right)^2}=\dfrac{1+x^2}{|1-x^2|}$

$\sin y=\dfrac{\tan y}{\sec y}=?$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\tan^{-1}x=y,-\dfrac\pi2<y<\dfrac\pi2\ \ \ \ (1)$

and $\sin^{-1}\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}=\sin^{-1}(\sin2y)=n\pi+(-1)^n(2y)=f(y)$  where $n$ is an integer such that $-\dfrac\pi2\le f(y)\le\dfrac\pi2$

If $n=0,-\dfrac\pi2\le2y\le\dfrac\pi2\iff-1\le x\le1$

If $n=1,-\dfrac\pi2\le\pi-2y\le\dfrac\pi2\iff\dfrac{3\pi}2\ge2y\ge\dfrac\pi2$  but $2y<\pi$ by $(1)$ $\implies\dfrac\pi2\le2y<\pi\implies x\ge1$

Similarly,  $n=-1,-\dfrac\pi2\le-\pi-2y\le\dfrac\pi2\iff x\le1$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1+x²}\right)-2\tan^{-1}(x)$ and examine

$$f’(x) =\left( \frac{1-x^2}{|1-x^2|}-1\right)\frac2{1+x^2}$$

which is apparent that, only for $x\in[-1,1]$, $f’(x)=0$ with the two functions equal to each other.